# No logro ubicar el formulario al final de la vista haciendo slimScroll al div del chat

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, adminlte

Intento que el formulario de chat se ubique al final de la vista, teniendo en cuenta que intento hacer [slimScroll](https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll) el `div` que contiene la conversación.

Este es el código de mi plantilla base:

```
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue-light fixed" style="overflow-y: hidden;">
        <!-- Site wrapper -->
        <div class="wrapper">
            <header class="main-header">
                <!-- Logo -->
                {% set inicio = path('app_homepage', {'modulo':app.session.get('modulo')|default('embarazadas')}) %}
                {% if (is_granted('ROLE_EST_HOSP') or is_granted('ROLE_EST_HOMA')) %}
                    {% set inicio = path('unidadIngresos_index', {'modulo':app.session.get('modulo')|default('embarazadas')}) %}
                {% elseif is_granted('ROLE_MEDICO') %}
                    {% set inicio = path('medico_inicio', {'modulo':app.session.get('modulo')|default('embarazadas')}) %}
                {% endif %}
                <a href="{{ inicio }}" class="logo">
                    <!-- mini logo for sidebar mini 50x50 pixels -->
                    <span class="logo-mini"><b>PAMI</b></span>
                    <!-- logo for regular state and mobile devices -->
                    <span class="logo-lg"><b>PAMI</b>Web</span>
                </a>
                <!-- Header Navbar: style can be found in header.less -->
                <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top">                    
                    <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
                    {% block menuPrincipal %} {{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\AppController::renderMenuPrincipalAction')) }} {% endblock %}

                    <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <!-- Notificaciones buzon interno -->
                            {{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\AppController::seccionNotificacionesBuzonInternoMenuPrincipalAction')) }}
                            <!-- Notificaciones -->
                            {{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\AppController::seccionNotificacionesMenuPrincipalAction')) }}
                            <!-- Chat -->
                            {{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\AppController::seccionNotificacionesChatMenuPrincipalAction')) }}
                            <!-- User Account: style can be found in dropdown.less -->
                            <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <img src="{{ asset('images/user.png')}}"  class="user-image" alt="User Image" />
                                    <span class="hidden-xs">{{ app.user.username }}</span>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <!-- User image -->
                                    <li class="user-header">
                                        <img src="{{ asset('images/user.png')}}"  class="img-circle" alt="User Image" />
                                        <p>
                                            {{ app.user.nombreCompleto }}
                                            <small>{{ app.user.rol.nombreRol }}</small>
                                        </p>
                                    </li>
                                    <!-- Menu Body -->
                                    <li class="user-body">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                                                <a href="{{ asset('ayuda.pdf') }}" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-4x fa-question-circle"></i></a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <!-- Menu Footer-->
                                    <li class="user-footer">
                                        <div class="pull-left">
                                            <a data-src="{{ path('usuario_cambiarContrasenha') }}" class="lnkCambiarContrasenha btn btn-primary btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-key"></i>&nbsp;Cambiar Contrase&ntilde;a</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="pull-right">
                                            <a href="{{ path('usuario_logout') }}" class="btn btn-warning btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>&nbsp;Salir</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </header>

            <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
            <div class="content-wrapper" style="width: 100hw; margin-left: 0px;" id="principal">
                <section class="content">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                            <div class="box box-primary">
                                <div class="box-header with-border">
                                    <h3 class="box-title"><i class="fa fa-wechat"></i>&nbsp;Sala de Chat</h3>
                                    <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                                        <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-flat" href="{{ path('app_chat') }}"><span class="fa fa-refresh"></span>&nbsp;Actualizar</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>                                
                                <div class="box-body chat">
                                    {% block room %}{% endblock %}
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.box-body -->
                                <div class="box-footer">
                                    {{ form_start(formMensaje, {id:"chatroom-form"}) }}
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        {{ form_widget(formMensaje.texto) }}
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <label id="labelCaracteresRestantes"></label>
                                        </span>
                                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnEnviarMensaje">Enviar</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    {{ form_end(formMensaje)}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
            <!-- /.content-wrapper -->

            {% block footer %}
                <!--
                <footer class="main-footer" style="margin-left: 0px;">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <strong>Copyright &copy; 2017- 2021</strong>
                    </div>
                </footer>
                -->
            {% endblock %}

        </div>
        <!-- ./wrapper -->
    </body>
```

Tengo entendido que slimScroll funciona sobre un div cuando este sobrepasa la altura, en este caso, establecida en el parámetro `height`.

Código de la vista que incluye la conversación dentro del bloque `{% block room %}{% endblock %}`

```
{% extends 'base_chat.html.twig' %}

{% block room %}
    <div  style="width: 100hw; min-height: 90vh; height: 90vh; overflow-y: hidden;" id="chat-conversations" data-sender="{{ sender }}">
        {% for msg in ultimosMensajes %}
            <div class="item" id="{{ msg.idPublico|uuid_encode }}" data-sender="{{ msg.sender }}">
                <img src="{{ asset('images/user.png') }}" {% if sender == msg.sender %}class="online"{% endif %}>

                <p class="message">
                    <a class="name lnkCursorPuntero">
                        <small class="text-muted pull-right"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> {{ msg.fechaCreado|date('d/m/Y h:i a') }}</small>
                        {{ msg.sender }}
                    </a>
                    {{ msg.texto }}
                </p>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>    
{% endblock %}
```

Le intento hacer slimScroll al `div` con `id="chat-conversations"`:

```
$('#chat-conversations').slimScroll({
        height: ($(window).height() - $('.main-header').height() + 50) + 'px',
        alwaysVisible: false,
        start: 'bottom'
    });
```

El formulario está en la plantilla base como footer del elemento `section`

Intenté darle un alto al div de conversaciones pero no logro el objetivo, incluso quitando las medidas y poniendo la propiedad height del slimScroll a un 50% de la altura del contenido provoca que el úlitmo mensaje que llegue no se muestre, quede oculto. Esto es lo que ocurre, la región marcada en rojo es la que le hago slimScroll, y la marcada en azul es el formulario que deseo se ubique al final.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Según veo es un plugin un poco viejo, pues su [github](https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll) actualizó por última vez su código 7 o más años atrás.  Quizás no funcione bien con los jquery actuales. Y los [comentarios de su página](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll) también son un poco antediluvianos. No se si deberías buscar alternativas.

Comment: @masterguru la verdad es que lo usé porque está incluido en adminlte. buscaré otra opción entonces en caso que no logre funcione adecuadamente.

Comment: mmm... entonces no se, si está integrado allí será porque les funciona... a menos que hayas actualizado por tu cuenta el jquery que usen ellos o algo similar, eso ya no lo sé... no me fijé bien en lo del adminlte y quizás ellos lo han seguido usando y actualizando por su cuenta y debería funcionar bien.

Comment: Creo más bien se trata de desconocimiento mío al manejar las alturas de los div, El efecto del slimScroll se logra, solo que no a la altura necesaria para que el div del formulario se muestra totalmente.